# Can I assign any post into specific pages?

Tags: wordpress, post

I need to use Wordpress Blog as my webpage. And I need to assign any post into page such as...

I have three pages like

```
Page -> Dog, Cat, Bird
```

And I need to post

```
A to page Bird

B to page Bird

C to page Cat

D to page Dog

E to page Cat
```

And post A, B, C is in same category. Something like this.

I try to create new page but it cannot assign page into it.

How can I do it? or any plugin helping me to solve this problem.

**Thank you...**

Answer (score 0):

I think whate you're looking for is a "page of posts". Except the home page, other pages can't handle multiple posts by default.

Check this guide for more info:
http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/create-page-posts-wordpress-417.html